# Keep portfolio form when using GetPortfolioItem function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I used `GetPortfolioItem` function to refer the portfolio (text file) from Email studio to my Email content in Content Builder. But it seemed it couldn't keep its original form in preview mode. Exactly it omitted every break in the portfolio. So how to solve this issue?

My code:

```
%%[
    var @portfolioItemKey
    set @portfolioItemKey = "PSA portfolio" /* external key */
]%%
%%=GetPortfolioItem(@portfolioItemKey)=%%
```

E.g. the portfolio:

```
My 1st line.
My 2nd line.
```

and it returned the output. It wasn't what I expected.

```
My 1st line. My 2nd line.
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually we can solve this issue by adding HTML tag into the portfolio file before we upload the file.
Note: I added `<br>` tag into the file and then it worked well.